# Split CSV columns into rows and match across column

Tags: oracle

I have a table which has data in below format.

```
PK COL1          COl2 
r1 abc,abd       zyx,xyz 
r2 bde,cse,bxo   ajy,bix,rxo 
r3 zde,cse,bxo   ajy,xir,sxo
```

The sequence of entries in COL1 maps to COL2 i.e. on r1, abc maps to zyx, abd maps to xyz. Dont ask me who came up with this idea :)

So now I have a requirement to transform this into a regular relational structure.

```
PK COL1 COL2
r1 abc  zyx
r1 abd  xyz
r2 bde  ajy  
r2 cse  bix
r2 bxo  rxo
r3 zde  ajy  
r3 cse  xir
r3 bxo  sxo
```

I have looked at the other examples that are available for converting CSV columns into rows. All those works fine for single CSV column. But with 2 CSV columns, a) how do I get it to work and b) also ensure that the mapping sequence is not disturbed. Any suggestions?

Thanks
askids

Comment: Forgot to mention. We are on oracle 11g. The 3 byte length of individual values is not fixed. it can vary from row to row and between col1 and col2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with
     test_data ( pk, col1, col2 ) as ( 
       select 'r1', 'abc,abd'    , 'zyx,xyz'     from dual union all 
       select 'r2', 'bde,cse,bxo', 'ajy,bix,rxo' from dual union all 
       select 'r3', 'zde,cse,bxo', 'ajy,xir,sxo' from dual
     )
-- end of test data, SQL query begins below this line
select pk, 
       regexp_substr(col1, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as col1,
       regexp_substr(col2, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as col2
from   test_data
connect by level <= length(col1) - length(replace(col1, ',')) + 1
       and prior pk = pk
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
;

PK  COL1  COL2
--  ----  ----
r1  abc   zyx
r1  abd   xyz
r2  bde   ajy
r2  cse   bix
r2  bxo   rxo
r3  zde   ajy
r3  cse   xir
r3  bxo   sxo
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note, if col1 or col2 may contain empty values in between commas, you need more complex regexp:

```
SQL> select
  t.pk,
  regexp_substr(t.col1, '[^,]+',1,ordno.n) as col1,
  regexp_substr(t.col2, '[^,]+',1,ordno.n) as col2
from (
  select 'r1' pk, 'abc,abd' col1, 'zyx,xyz' col2 from dual union all
  select 'r2' pk, 'bde,cse,bxo' col1, 'ajy,bix,rxo' col2 from dual union all
  select 'r3' pk, 'zde,cse,bxo' col1, 'ajy,xir,sxo' col2 from dual
  ) t
  join (select level n from dual connect by level <= 1000) ordno
    on ordno.n <= regexp_count(t.col1, '[^,]+')
order by t.pk;

PK COL1        COL2      
-- ----------- -----------
r1 abc         zyx        
r1 abd         xyz        
r2 cse         bix        
r2 bxo         rxo        
r2 bde         ajy        
r3 zde         ajy        
r3 bxo         sxo        
r3 cse         xir        

 8 rows selected
```